# Aggrid Enterprise trigger onExpandOrContract onRowClicked

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am trying to use the enterprise model but when grouping (full row group), I can only expand/collapse on the small icon.

I want the whole row to be clickable, but enterprise doesn't use onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed and there's no other way to trigger onExpandOrContract function.

Can you please suggest a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I realized I can use redrawRows to get things done.